# DatagridCell style overriden by TextBox style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, textbox, styles

I have a `Style` for `DataGridCell` (only triggers are important.)

```xml
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"   BorderThickness="0"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4, 0, 0, 0"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It works when I define column like this:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column1" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1, Mode=OneWay}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But when I have `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock` like this:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Column1">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Property1, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It doesn't work since `TextBox` has it's own `Style`. 
I need to use `TextBox` because I want to let the user select the text from cell. But also I need the `Foreground` color to change when the **cell/row** is selected.

> *(Background color is dark and foreground color is light, but when a cell/row is selected   then the background color is light and foreground color should be dark)*

**EDIT**

I edited my question to be more clear. Sorry for previous misunderstandings. My goal here is to have `TextBox` in `DataGridCell` and use `Trigger`s from `DataGridCellStyle`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not leaving/taking the Textblock/Textbox style instead. *You put a textbox in there and a textbox has a background.*

Try setting the TextBox background to transparent. I'd also suggest removing the textbox borders as well if all you want is to select the text from the cell.

You can set the following properties to get the look you want.

`Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True"`

To set the foreground on the TextBox

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Name="Display" Text=.../>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                     Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Display" Property="Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DarkForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I am really sorry. Maybe I did not explain myself enough... There is no problem with Setting textbox background to Transparent... real problem is that textbox has still its own foreground and not a foreground of cell... so it's not changed when the row is selected. see those triggers in DataGridCellStyle

Comment: Got it. Fixed. I just solved this identical problem on another question like an hour ago.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well. It's not global solution, but it sure is an answer. Cheers.