# Copy text from DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to be able to copy text from DataGrid Cell.

1. First possible solution could be setting `SelectionUnit` to `Cell` but that's not an option for me since I need to select `FullRow`
2. Second possible approach was to have `DataGridTemplateColumn` with readonly `TextBox` in it. But there is an issue with styles. My previous question: [DatagridCell style overriden by TextBox style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15007273/1456174). I need really bright color for text in row, but really dark in selected row.
3. Third is to set IsReadOnly="False" on DataGrid and provide `EditingElementStyle`for `DataGridTextColumn`

   ```
   <Style x:Key="EditingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
   </Style>
   ...  
   <DataGridTextColumn ... EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource EditingStyle}"/>
   ```

   But here comes a really terrible bug [WPF Datagrid Text Column allows one character text enter when the internal text box is set to read only.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624239/wpf-datagrid-text-column-allows-one-character-text-enter-when-the-internal-text-box-is-set-to-read-only)

Do you know about some different solution for this? Or workaround? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I noticed that `DataGrid` from [*Extended WPF Toolkit*](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home) doesn't have this **bug**, but it seems it has different structure and I wouldn't be able ty apply my DataGrid Style.

I noticed that using ReadOnly TextBox as EditingElementStyle of DataGridColumn brings further problems. When you use **OneWay** binding then it's not possible to get cell to **Editing state**. It's not acceptable to let the user override for example **ID** of some entity displayed in DataGrid. So it has to be somehow readonly or at least **OneWay** binding.

At this moment I have no solution for this at all. Is there any other way to let the user copy from cell while the row is selected and highlighted? Have I failed to notice some other solution? Thanks for reading.

Comment: is your Row an Object?

Comment: @WiiMaxx DataGrid's ItemsSource is bound for example to `ObservableCollection<Foo>` and columns are based on properties of `Foo` In Column1 is Foo.Property1 and so on.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could do something dirty to get the current cell. In your xaml just add

```
<DataGrid GotFocus="DataGrid_GotFocus" KeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown">
```

and in code-behind

```
private void DataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell)
        _currentCell = (DataGridCell) e.OriginalSource;
}

private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.C && (e.SystemKey == Key.LeftCtrl || e.SystemKey == Key.RightCtrl))
    {
         //Transform content here, like
         Clipboard.SetText(_currentCell.Content);
    }
}
```

This should do it, because `GotFocus` gets executed everytime the selection changed in the data grid itself.

Comment: It won't work for me. Because I don't have code-behind so far and I am not going to break it now. Plus my cells are not focusable, but Thank you.